# Scripting error after bc command

Tags: shell, shell-script

I am trying to execute a script as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
USED=`free -m | more | grep -v total | head -1 | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f18`
CACHE=`free -m | more | grep -v Swap | tail -1 | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f9`
TOTAL=`free -m | more | grep -v total | head -1 | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f11`
echo "scale=2 ; ((($USED - $CACHE) /$TOTAL) *100)" | bc
```

But I always get the following error:

```
(standard_in) 1: parse error
```

Comment: remove `more` from your pipelines, it is only useful for humans, not `grep`

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the pipe to bc `| bc`, then run your script, it will output:

```
scale=2 ; (((5538 - ) / 5969) * 100)
```

You can see `$CACHE` variable is null, causing `bc` syntax error.

You can try:

```
CACHE=$(free -m | more | grep -v Swap | tail -1 | cut -d':' -f2 | awk '{print $1}')
```

**NOTE**

- Use `awk` to parse output is better than `cut` in this case.
- You should try **$(...)** for command substitution.

Comment: I'd go for using `awk` (nawk) to dispatch with the `grep`, `head`, `tail` and `cut` altogether ;-) And `more`? Is the output of `free` colorized perhaps? (FWIW, parsing `vmstat -s` for this kind of task is easier and more portable.)

Comment: @mr.spuratic: I have not actually done something like this before. I only help the OP solved this problem. But I think do something directly with `proc` is a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/bash
USED=**0**
free -m | more | grep -v total | head -1 | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f18

CACHE=**0**
free -m | more | grep -v Swap | tail -1 | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f9
TOTAL=**0**
free -m | more | grep -v total | head -1 | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f11
echo "scale=2 ; ((($USED - $CACHE) /$TOTAL) *100)" | bc
```

Comment: It's not clear how this answers the question. You should add some explanation for how this code differs from and solves the problem in the original code. Though, a quick look shows that this code has more issues than the original code (`CACHE=**0**`). Finally, you should take some care to format posts so that they are readable; user has already suggested an edit to format the code.